# Resize Navigation Bar based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a nav sidebar which includes some content. I would like to resize its height dynamically based on what is inside my sidebar. I have tried deleting the height option, however that doesn't seem to work. I am really stumped and would like some help.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <?php
            if(hasMediaFile(wp_title($sep = '', $display = false, $seplocation = ''),"images.txt")) :
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#images">
                <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                            Images
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php
            if(hasMediaFile(wp_title($sep = '', $display = false, $seplocation = ''),"videos.txt")) :
        ?>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#videos">
                <i class="fa fa-play fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                            Videos
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php
            if(hasMediaFile(wp_title($sep = '', $display = false, $seplocation = ''),"audios.txt")) :
        ?>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#audio">
                <i class="fa fa-headphones fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                            Audios
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            if(hasMediaFile(wp_title($sep = '', $display = false, $seplocation = ''),"gviewdocs.txt")) :
        ?>
        <li class="has-subnav">
            <a href="#documents">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                            Documents
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
            if(hasMediaFile(wp_title($sep = '', $display = false, $seplocation = ''),"snapshots.txt")) :
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#websites">
                <i class="fa  fa-link fa-2x"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">
                            Websites
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
  width:250px;
  overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
  background:#212121;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top:50px;
  bottom:0;
  height: 20%;
  left:30px;
  width:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
  transition:width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
  z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
  margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
  position:relative;
  display:table;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  color:#999;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
  transition:all .1s linear;

}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
  width:60px;
  height:36px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
  position:relative;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

Here is a preview of what this currently outputs:

With three elements: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SLym.jpg

With Five elements: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5HX3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.main-menu`'s height to `fit-content`.

Like this:

```css
.main-menu {
  background:#212121;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top:50px;
  bottom:0;
  height: fit-content;
  /* height: 20%; */
  left:30px;
  width:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
  transition:width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: or simply remove the height and the bottom:0

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `height` CSS property to `fit-content`. [More about fit-content on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)